# How to add class to an img object in DOM,PHP?

Tags: php, dom

Here is piece of code

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
```

Into `$imgs` goes DOM img tag. Now I want to change the original img tag by adding some class to it.

SO if the `$article_header` was this:

```
"some text"...<img src = 'http://some_source'>...some text...
```

Now I want it to become this:

```
"some text"...<img class = 'someclass' src = 'http://some_source'>...some text...
```

**UPDATE**

I repeat. Start variable is `$article_header`.
So all changes must be done to it.

With my code I just search through `$article_header` for img tags , finding them putting them into some variables and change them there is ok, but how can I put all changes back to `$article_header` ???

Comment: I think there might be a way simpler solution using just css. Can you show us what you need all that for?

Comment: Now I think it's a bit complicated to do it with css. I have tinymce and user inserts image into it , when tiny posts it to php , I need images to have some class so later when user views the result javascript could fire some image gallery on image click targeting class

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your foreach loop, call `$img->setAttribute('class', 'someclass');`. This should do the trick. See more at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php

Then you need to save the modified document back using  `$article_header = $doc->saveXml();`.

Comment: Ok I will add class to $img, but problem is $article_header will remain the same. How to change things there ?

Comment: I edited my answer to add that part. The second part has to be done outside the foreach otherwise it's a bit wasteful.

Comment: Be aware this will replace any existing classes, not add to them.

Answer (score 17):

If you know that the element will not have a class set already you can just use [`DOMElement::setAttribute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php), like:

```
$img->setAttribute('class','someClass');
```

If you are not sure if the element might already have a class set, then you should do a getAttribute() first and then add your class to the list of classes.

Comment: HI
using DOM to get / change the class tag, and then saving it back by $doc->saveXML(); produces a full ducument with t"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">" which gets in the way..how to get rid of them, aside from trimming the data ?