# php dom - add class on child elements

Tags: php, dom

I have some html content in a variable php .. $html

I want to add a class (myClass) only at the 'img' includes in all the 'table' (not at the  out...)

```html
<?php
$html = <<aaa
<img src="..." alt="..." />
<table class="..">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="..." alt="..." /></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- more rows ...  -->
</table>
<!-- other tables with img -->
aaa;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
/*
here, I have to find the table_child <img> and add the class myClass Es. <img class="myClass" .. />
*/
/*
store the new content in a new variabile $html_edit
*/
print "$html_edit";
/*
like this:
$html_edit = <<aaa
<img src="..." alt="..." />
<table class="..">
  <tr>
    <td><img class="myClass" src="..." alt="..." /></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- more rows ...  -->
</table>
<!-- other tables with <img class="myClass" -->
aaa;
*/
?>
```

how can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add class to an img object in DOM,PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056624/how-to-add-class-to-an-img-object-in-dom-php)

Comment: Isn't a duplicate, I want to add class only at the 'img' child of 'table', not to all 'img' in the html

Comment: First select table tag, and then use that answer to apply class.

Answer (score 2):

Think about your search - it is in two layers - first to find the Tables, then the Images within those Tables. Then use [the `setAttribute()` function](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php).

```
$html = <<<EOT
    <img src="..." alt="Outside the Table - No Change" />
    <table class="theTableClass">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="..." alt="The Target Image #1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="..." alt="The Target Image #2" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <img src="..." alt="Outside the Table - No Change Again" />
    <table class="theTableClass">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="..." alt="The Target Image #3" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Just Text Here</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
EOT;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// First Find each of the TABLEs and Loop
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
foreach ($tables as $k => $table)
{
    // Within Each Table, Find the IMGs and Loop
    $imgs = $table->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($imgs as $k2 => $img)
    {
        // Set the IMGs Class attribute to whatever you want
        $img->setAttribute('class', 'myClass');
    }
}

// Save the modified HTML back to the variable
$html = $dom->saveHTML();

echo $html;
```

Comment: thank You so much, this solution works fine if I use $dom->loadHTML($html);  but if I use $dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);  the class is added to all the images !

Comment: Then don’t use those additional settings? Or do you have a specific need for them?

Comment: the content in $html is recovered in a database and it's the content of posts in my cms. Then I don't need to re-print the document information ecc